# how to remove blank space from web page?

Tags: html, css

I Have one Problem by web page design.can't remove this space from page!

by this style:

```
<body>
   <div style="width:100%;" >
      ss
   </div>
```

please see this picture of my page:

[image]

Comment: set margin to 0 in css body { margin: 0; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nullify the margin of document, add this style to your web page

```
<style>
html, body{
   margin: 0;
}
</style>
```